# How to seed a recursive c++ function

Tags: c++, c++11, random

I wrote this short program to randomly pick a subset of m elements out of {1,...,n} -

```
std::set<int> randSubSet(int n, int m){
  // generates a random subset of m elements from {1,...,n} uniformly

  if (m>n) //check inputs validity
    throw std::invalid_argument("m is larger then n.");

  std::set<int> res{}; //initialize result set

  if (m==n){ //easy case - the full set
     for(int i = 1 ; i<n ; ++i)
         res.insert(i);
  }

  std::mt19937 eng;
  std::uniform_int_distribution<> uni(1,n);

  if ( m == 0 ){ // recursion base case

      return res;
  }
  else {
      res = randSubSet(n-1,m-1);
      int i = uni(eng);
      if (res.find(i) == res.end()) // if i isn't in S add it
          res.insert(i);
      else
          res.insert(n); //else add n

  }
  return res;
}
```

Since eng isn't seeded I always get the same answer. How do I seed eng in this senario? (since each call has it's own engine)

I can avoid the problem using a global variable, I was wondering if there is any better solution. Thanks!

Comment: Use a static variable, and initialize it to `0`. Each time you enter the function, check if it's `0`. If it is, seed the PRNG, and change the value to `1`. If it's not, do nothing.

Comment: Use a static variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass the random engine as an argument to the function, so that the same engine is used in every recursion step. The signature of your function will become `std::set<int> randSubSet(int n, int m, std::mt19937& eng)`. You then need to pass a random engine in order to use the function, so you can create an overload that does not take a random engine, and have that call your function with a default random engine (constructed in the same way that you do now).

Answer (score 0):

The easy way to have a recursive function "seeded" is to wrap it in a non-recursive one: you just write a non-recursive function that does the setup and then calls the recursive one to do the job.

An alternative that may be meaningful is to use a default `init=true` parameter: inside the recursive function you call yourself passing `init=false`.